# How to navigate back to a variable starting location with Navigation Component

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using the Android Navigation Component to navigate. But i'm facing a problem.

I'm going to try to explain my problem as simple as possible:

Imagine there are 3 Fragments: A, B and C.
And that we can navigate from A to B and from B to C (A -> B -> C)

But also imagine that there's another fragment that leads to B, for example fragment X.

How can i get back to Fragment X or A from fragment C, based upon whether the user started from A or X?

Is there an existing solution to deal with this are do i have to provide a custom implementation for this?

Answer (score 0):

To the action tag that lead from B to C in your navigation file add these lines :

```
app:popUpTo ="idOfFragmentB"
app:popUpToInclusive = "true"
```

Comment: Yea but what do i put as destination because that's what's variable

Comment: Of course you will put C as destination .